# How to make a fluid layout equally spaced

Tags: html, css, user-interface, flexbox, user-experience

My problem is both a design and code issue, I have a diagonal layout which consists of a paragraph of text paired with an image which is then flipped (image then paragraph) on the next row.

**The problem is** I don't know the height of the paragraph or the height of the image so how do I make it equally spaced for the end user?

[Here is a fiddle that may help explain my question.](https://jsfiddle.net/4ax1qjbc/)

My code:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="one">
        <p>

        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="two">
        <img src="https://cdn.jamesedition.com/media/W1siZiIsImxpc3RpbmdfaW1hZ2VzLzIwMTcvMDkvMDkvMjEvNTgvNDUvMGJkYTRmYTMtMTY1Yy00YmQzLThhZTEtNTlhNzc2NGYwNDBjL3AxLUoycDhOV0xHdnM4RDNVdUphaW5xRWxMMWxEcnpaQzlyNXg0a2xKREUuanBnIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCIyMDAweCJdLFsicCIsIndhdGVybWFyayJdLFsicCIsImVuY29kZSIsImpwZyIsIi1zdHJpcCAtcXVhbGl0eSA4MCAtaW50ZXJsYWNlIFBsYW5lIl1d/2015-lamborghini-aventador-roadster.jpg?sha=6b14013f088579ce">
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container">

    <div class="two">
        <img src="https://cdn.jamesedition.com/media/W1siZiIsImxpc3RpbmdfaW1hZ2VzLzIwMTcvMDkvMDkvMjEvNTgvNDUvMGJkYTRmYTMtMTY1Yy00YmQzLThhZTEtNTlhNzc2NGYwNDBjL3AxLUoycDhOV0xHdnM4RDNVdUphaW5xRWxMMWxEcnpaQzlyNXg0a2xKREUuanBnIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCIyMDAweCJdLFsicCIsIndhdGVybWFyayJdLFsicCIsImVuY29kZSIsImpwZyIsIi1zdHJpcCAtcXVhbGl0eSA4MCAtaW50ZXJsYWNlIFBsYW5lIl1d/2015-lamborghini-aventador-roadster.jpg?sha=6b14013f088579ce">
    </div>

    <div class="one">
        <p>

        </p>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container">

    <div class="three">
        <p>

        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="two">
        <img src="https://cdn.jamesedition.com/media/W1siZiIsImxpc3RpbmdfaW1hZ2VzLzIwMTcvMDkvMDkvMjEvNTgvNDUvMGJkYTRmYTMtMTY1Yy00YmQzLThhZTEtNTlhNzc2NGYwNDBjL3AxLUoycDhOV0xHdnM4RDNVdUphaW5xRWxMMWxEcnpaQzlyNXg0a2xKREUuanBnIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCIyMDAweCJdLFsicCIsIndhdGVybWFyayJdLFsicCIsImVuY29kZSIsImpwZyIsIi1zdHJpcCAtcXVhbGl0eSA4MCAtaW50ZXJsYWNlIFBsYW5lIl1d/2015-lamborghini-aventador-roadster.jpg?sha=6b14013f088579ce">
    </div>

</div>

.one{
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.two{
  float:left;
  height:auto;
  background:blue;
  width:50%;

}
.three{
  float:left;
  height:400px;
  background:blue;
  width:50%;

}
.container{
  height:auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
}
img{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
```

Class one is the paragraph ( shorter paragraph )
Class .two is the picture
Class .three is a longer paragraph

as you can see row one and two are equally spaced but row three has a larger space which wont look good to the end user.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want both columns to be the same height at all times?

Comment: No, I need the image to resize to the size of the paragraph (left) column without any of the image being cut off .

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `img` and use `background-image` and `background-size: cover`. With that you can make the image to completely cover the space left.

Stack snippet

```css
.one {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.two {
  background: url('https://cdn.jamesedition.com/media/W1siZiIsImxpc3RpbmdfaW1hZ2VzLzIwMTcvMDkvMDkvMjEvNTgvNDUvMGJkYTRmYTMtMTY1Yy00YmQzLThhZTEtNTlhNzc2NGYwNDBjL3AxLUoycDhOV0xHdnM4RDNVdUphaW5xRWxMMWxEcnpaQzlyNXg0a2xKREUuanBnIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCIyMDAweCJdLFsicCIsIndhdGVybWFyayJdLFsicCIsImVuY29kZSIsImpwZyIsIi1zdHJpcCAtcXVhbGl0eSA4MCAtaW50ZXJsYWNlIFBsYW5lIl1d/2015-lamborghini-aventador-roadster.jpg?sha=6b14013f088579ce') center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1ps solid red;
  width: 50%;
}

.three {
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="one">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="two">   
  </div>
  <div class="one">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="container">

  <div class="three">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or if the whole picture should be visible, use `background-size: contain` instead.

Stack snippet

```css
.one {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.two {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.jamesedition.com/media/W1siZiIsImxpc3RpbmdfaW1hZ2VzLzIwMTcvMDkvMDkvMjEvNTgvNDUvMGJkYTRmYTMtMTY1Yy00YmQzLThhZTEtNTlhNzc2NGYwNDBjL3AxLUoycDhOV0xHdnM4RDNVdUphaW5xRWxMMWxEcnpaQzlyNXg0a2xKREUuanBnIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCIyMDAweCJdLFsicCIsIndhdGVybWFyayJdLFsicCIsImVuY29kZSIsImpwZyIsIi1zdHJpcCAtcXVhbGl0eSA4MCAtaW50ZXJsYWNlIFBsYW5lIl1d/2015-lamborghini-aventador-roadster.jpg?sha=6b14013f088579ce');
  
  background-position: center center; /*  or "left top", and so on  */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;       /*  or "repeat-y", and so on  */
  background-size: contain;
  border: 1ps solid red;
  width: 50%;
}

.three {
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;       /*  or "repeat-y", and so on  */
  width: 50%;
}

.three + .two {                       /*  where class .two comes after .three  */
  background-repeat: repeat-y;        /*  repeat vertically  */
  background-position: center top;    /*  start at "center top"  */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="one">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="two">   
  </div>
  <div class="one">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="container">

  <div class="three">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment.

If the image shouldn't scale up, but scale down, you either need a script to detect the image size and toggle between `background-size: contain` (scale down) and `background-size: auto` (keep org. size), or, as shown below, using the `img`, combined with `transform` to center it. The latter won't allow to control *repeat* though.

Stack snippet

```css
.one {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

.two {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.two img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.three {
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="one">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="two">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="one">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="container">

  <div class="three">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but now the third image is being cut off, I would need to show the full third image.

Comment: @user9174675 Added a 2nd sample. And I hope you understand, it is either of these 2, or you will have to adjust the image to the text or have it stretched (which would make it loose its aspect ratio).

Comment: Hi , The issue with this is that the image may be smaller than 50% width , in that case how would I handle repeat and how would I center it.

Comment: @user9174675 I updated my 2nd sample and added some notes to its CSS. Does those notes help?

Comment: I tried your solution , and it worked for images that were bigger than the div ( scaled them down perfectly ) however images that were smaller than the div scaled up and looked blurry . Any solution for this ?

Comment: @user9174675 No, as when a small image scale up too much, many pixels need to be doubled to many times, hence the overall quality goes down, which is the opposite for bigger.

Comment: I don't want it to scale up , any way of stopping it from scaling up. Thanks for all the help by the way.

Comment: @user9174675 Added a 3rd sample + info